# Reading Advertisement data in linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, packet-sniffers

I have libelum sensor node working with BLE module and i am trying to send "hello world " message from this module and i want to read this message from my Linux device (laptop) ,i have tried with the below command and  can see the row data by using

## hcidump -t -X -i hci1

and

## hcitool lescan

the result from the above command is

> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 25
>       LE Advertising Report
>         ADV_IND - Connectable undirected advertising (0)
>         bdaddr 00:07:80:7E:AC:16 (Public)
>         Flags: 0x06
>         Complete service classes: 0x1800 0x180a 0x1803 0x1802
>         RSSI: -70
>   HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 29
>       LE Advertising Report
>         SCAN_RSP - Scan Response (4)
>         bdaddr 00:07:80:7E:AC:16 (Public)
>         Complete local name: '...............'
>         RSSI: -70

i have also tried with

## btmon

the result from this command show me the data size but not the packet

> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 29                       [hci1] 3.494912
>         LE Advertising Report (0x02)
>           Num reports: 1
>           Event type: Scan response - SCAN_RSP (0x04)
>           Address type: Public (0x00)
>           Address: 00:07:80:7E:AC:16 (Bluegiga Technologies OY)
>           Data length: 17
>           Name (complete): 
>           RSSI: -62 dBm (0xc2)

My first question is is ,is it possible to see(read) the packets ("hello world") in my laptop? how ? i am using bluez-5.18.

Answer (score 0):

Have you trie doing

```
hcidump -XYRt
```